# Openstack placement-status upgrade check giving not initialized error

Tags: openstack, oslo

I am trying to install openstack Wallaby on Ubuntu 20.04. I already installed Keystone and Glance and they work as expected. But after I installed Placement and tried to verify it using 'placement-status upgrade check' I constantly get the same error.

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_upgradecheck/upgradecheck.py", line 196, in run
    return conf.command.action_fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_upgradecheck/upgradecheck.py", line 104, in check
    result = func_name(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_upgradecheck/common_checks.py", line 41, in check_policy_json
    policy_path = conf.find_file(conf.oslo_policy.policy_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2543, in find_file
    raise NotInitializedError()
oslo_config.cfg.NotInitializedError: call expression on parser has not been invoked
```

Is this normal at this stage or am I doing something wrong here?

I already checked the database connections (user and password work and database is made). And I also checked the username, password and url options in keystone_authtoken in placement.conf but I can't find what's wrong.

Comment: Same problem here... Did you get success with the installation process?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem with Wallaby on Ubuntu 20.04. I solved it with installing Placement from PyPI instead of Ubuntu package manager so far. You should consider how implement starting Placement automatically if you install Placement from this instruction.

- Install and configure Placement from PyPI
  https://docs.openstack.org/placement/wallaby/install/from-pypi.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so changed to Victoria, same issue. Digging about in the docs though I found the issue. The command that populate the database looks similar for Keystone, Glance and Placement but for placement the command should be 'su -s /bin/sh -c "placement-manage db sync" placement'. Notice that for placement it is 'db sync' not 'db_sync' as it is for the others. I created scripts, well actuall am using ansible and just cut and pasted between them and my guess is you have done the same. Basically as it does not run the database is empty hence the error.

Guy